# How to get editorconfig file from eslintrc file?

Tags: phpstorm, eslint, editorconfig

I'm trying to have a standard code style for my project, and I have found http://editorconfig.org/, that is a standard for that. I like it very much, and Intellij supports it (we use Intellij).

I have a .eslintrc file (extend from airbnb style).

So, how to get .editorconfig file from that .eslintrc file ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "So, how to get .editorconfig file from that .eslintrc file ?". Can you elaborate? If you include both files in the root directory of your project, Intellij will automatically use the `.editorconfig`. If you want to use ESLint with Intellij you'll need to use a package like https://github.com/idok/eslint-plugin , but it should also pick up and use the configuration in the root of your project.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a `.editorconfig` that configures the style enforced by the `eslint-config-airbnb` rules, you could use the `.editorconfig` file from that module's repo:

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/.editorconfig

Answer (score 1):

I found [eslint-to-editorconfig](https://github.com/sun1x/eslint-to-editorconfig) for this purpose, but I have had trouble getting it to work extending rules from the airbnb base rules. Perhaps you will have better luck:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/eslint-to-editorconfig  
/path/to/app/node_modules/eslint-to-editorconfig/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:402
            throw e;
            ^

Error: /path/to/app/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/es6.js:
    Configuration for rule "arrow-parens" is invalid:
    Value "as-needed,[object Object]" has more items than allowed.

Referenced from: airbnb-base
Referenced from: /path/to/app/.eslintrc
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a large and complete editorconfig is with IntelliJ.
You can change the settings as you want in the config and then extract the editorconfig

[image]